# magento 2 email body is blank

Tags: magento2, email

when  Magento sends emails (any email for any provider like Gmail, Hotmail), the emails are sent but with a blank body. the title and subject are visible but the body is empty
is there anyone that has the same problem?

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Graziano yes ...it was for another modules but i do not remember which module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because we have an error in other modules.
To fix this kind of bugs set Magento on developer mode and check the logs folder `var/log/`
you will find what you want

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue with the syntoax of your email template. Did you check the validity of your email template (syntax) ?

Comment: it was because we have an error in other modules